# Facebook Android SDK 3.0, publish feed dialog has a grey background

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm following the tutorial at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/ to implement a feed publish dialog in Android. When my dialog shows, about half of the  dialog on the bottom shows a grey background. It almost seems like the content of the dialog only take half of the screen and then it covers my view with the grey color. Has anyone came across this issue?

Comment: can u post a screenshot ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I just started using stackoverflow, I can't upload picture yet. Basically bottom half of the facebook feed publish dialog shows grey color.

Comment: hi, have you found any solutions yet for this problem? i'm having exactly the same problem with you. Here is the screenshot -> http://i.imgur.com/rL92MrM.png?1 ( I highlighted it with the red box )